# How can I merge horizontally three cells in Google Docs?

Tags: google-drive, google-docs

I want to merge (remove the separation lines between them) three cells horizontally in a Google document.

Answer (score -1):

select all three (shift click will work) then click the "Merge Cells" button on the top tool bar. Only the data in the left most cell will be kept.

Comment: Can you let me know where the "Merge Cells" button is? Remember that I'm talking about Google Docs. Thanks